# Counting number of queries satisfied by $or in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to search all documents in a collection, and sort them by the *amount of queries* they match?

i.e. documents that match 10 queries at the top, documents that match 1 at the bottom

I have been trying to implement this via an aggregation pipeline but I'm stuck.

For example, say I wanted to search for users between the ages of 18 & 24, as well as check the presence of a string using a regex:

```
db.users. aggregate({
    "$match": {
        '$or': [
            {
                "name": /.*m.*/
            },
            {
                'age': {
                    '$gt': 18,
                    '$lt': 24
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
```

I'm not sure where to go further than this though

Any help would be much appreciated

Edit:

Here is a sample collection:

```
users = [{
    'name': 'bob',
    'age': 19
},
{
    'name': 'susan',
    'age': 16
},
{
    'name': 'mark',
    'age': 25
},
{
    'name': 'matt',
    'age': 19
}]
```

Sample output after checking query 1: `regex /.*m.*/`, query 2: `18 < age < 24`:

```
[{
    'name': 'matt',
    'age': 19,
    'matched': 2
},
{
    'name': 'bob',
    'age': 19,
    'matched': 1
},
{
    'name': 'mark',
    'age': 25,
    'matched': 1
}]
```

Matt is first as he satisfied both queries.

Comment: Could you please add some sample collection and the expected output.

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet Yes, thank you for your help. I edited my main post.